# How can I solve my personal ORA-12154 error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, oracle, oracle11g

I need to run ASP.NET & C#.NET programs on the same Windows 2008 R2 server. You would think every thing would be a cakewalk, get one working and the other is a freebie.

I first installed Oracle XE on the server and got everything working. Migrated the DB, things were looking good.

I migrated the web app from a Windows 2003 x86 environment. It wouldn't work, So I installed the Oracle 11g (11.2x) x86 client, allowed 32 bit apps in the app pool and the web application work began working, I started doing a happy dance.

One part of the web app shells out and runs a C# executable (.exe) that resides in the bin folder of the web root. It wasn't working so I grabbed the shell command line and decided to run it manually. I get the error;

> Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

After trying a number of things I moved the executable to its own location, installed the Oracle 11g x64 client, put the oracle.dataaccess.dll into the folder with the applications (.exe) and now I get;

> ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

Everything including TNSPING connects just fine to the DB, I have the X64 path in the beginning of the path variable and I have tried as many ORA-12154 trouble shooting tips I can find, I am officially stumped. I have checked and double checked every TNSNAMES.ORA file on the system, and they all look good.

One question I have is "What blinking TNSNAMES.ORA is my program using?" Towards that end I downloaded and ran sysinternals ProcessExplorer, (as well as the built-in Resource Monitor(but I was unable to see it opening any files, let alone TNSNAMES.ORA.

Everything works swimmingly on the 2003 x86 server I copied it from.

Does anyoune have any constructive thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

Please ignore, after spending quite a number of hours slogging through C#, I am not a C# programmer, I discovered that the problem was a lack of understanding of how an open source module accessed the DB.

The program which displays an "error" message because it calls the connect method once with "default parameters" and then again with  the run time parameters.

Just shoot me.